# Setting axios base url dynamically

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios

i am getting base url from asyncstorage and i want to  set it as base url for axios instance.

currently iam following below code but it is not working

```
const axiosInstance = axios.create({
 // baseURL: API_END_POINTS.BASE_URL+AsyncStorage.getItem('dealerNo'),
});
axiosInstance.defaults.timeout = 10000000;
axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(
  async config => {
axiosInstance.defaults.baseURL=await getBaseUrl();
    return config;
  },
  error => Promise.reject(error)
);

  export async  function getBaseUrl() {
    var No = await AsyncStorage.getItem('dealerNo')
    var value =API_END_POINTS.BASE_URL+  No;
    return value;
  }


axiosInstance.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
export default axiosInstance;
```

iam importing the above axiosInstance to make get or post calls.

Comment: Wherer is get  function??

Comment: Does this code mean there's an error?

Comment: Hi  @hongdevelop.iam not getting error.But the base url is not setting.

Comment: @hongdevelop i have updated the code.Please check it once.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Make a function that returns the Axios instance with a dynamic base URL, like this:

***custom-axios.js***

```js
import axios from 'axios';

const customAxios = (dynamicBaseURL) => {
  // axios instance for making requests
  const axiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: dynamicBaseURL
  });

  return axiosInstance;
};

export default customAxios;
```

and then use the instance as follows:

```js
import axios from './custom-axios'

...
const axios1 = axios('/some-url');
const axios2 = axios('/another-url');

axios1.get('/base-is-some-url');
axios2.get('/base-is-another-url');
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Instaed of `axiosInstance.defaults.baseURL`, `config.baseURL = await getBaseURL();` is enough and should work.
At least it sets baseURL corrrectly in my side.